# Regex to find a string between something in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this two strings:

```
(username~contains~'ren'~and~status~contains~false)
(status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'ren')
```

i need one regex that find what is the status value after contains~

I try something like:

```
/(?<=status~contains~).*?(?=[)])|(?<=status~contains~).*?(?=~)/gi
```

pass in exemple 1: `(username~contains~'ren'~and~status~contains~false)` 
fail in exemple 2: `(status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'ren'`)

I need only the return true or false, but in the second exemple i get `false~and~username~contains~'ren'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you could change is to match either a `~` or `)`

```
(?<=status~contains~).*?(?=[)~])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FYUQcI/1)

Instead of using a lookbehind (which is not yet fully supported across browsers), you could also use a capturing group instead and make sure there are opening and closing parenthesis.

The value is in group 1.

```
\((?:[^~\r\n]+~)*status~contains~([^~\n]+)(?=[^()]*\))
```

- `\(` Match an opening `(`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^~\r\n]+~` Match 1+ times any char except `~` or a newline
- `)*` Close goup, repeat 0+ times
- `status~contains~` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^~\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `~` or a newline
- `)` Close group
- `(?=[^()]*\))` Positive lookahead, assert a closing `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bcrjyw/1)

```js
const regex = /\((?:[^~\r\n]+~)*status~contains~([^~\n]+)(?=[^()]*\))/g;
const str = `(username~contains~'ren'~and~status~contains~false)
(status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'ren')`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: the first example looks good, but the second without lookbehind don't pass, test it in reg site

Comment: @Jhonny In the second example the value is in the first capturing group. This is an example with a different engine selected which will highlight the groups in green. https://regex101.com/r/YNLdOO/1 You can get those matches using the example Javascript and it does not use lookarounds.

Comment: ooh, thanks for the explication. i will accept your answer because is the most explained

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/(?<=status~contains)~([^~)]+)[~)]/
```

and get group 1 from result.

Answer (score 1):

True or false `/^(?=.*status~contains~(true|false)).*/`
Use the multi-line option and  group 1 is the value.

https://regex101.com/r/N41U56/1

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?<=status~contains~)[^~)]+(?=[~)])/g
```

This uses a lookbehind of: `status~contains~` and a lookahead of either `~` or `)`. Therefore we can match 1 or more characters that are neither `~` nor `)` between the lookbehind and lookahead. This is simpler and more efficient than using `.*?`.

```js
let re = /(?<=status~contains~)[^~)]+(?=[~)])/g;
let text = "(username~contains~'ren'~and~status~contains~false)" +
           "(status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'ren')";
let m;
while (m = re.exec(text))
    console.log(m[0]);
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C7ZDHH/1)